# Best way of checking if a field exists and also another field matches a string in a Elasticsearch document?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
#First Document  
    { "fullname":"John", "age":70, "car":{"model":{"nickname":"nevan"}}}
#Second Document

{ "fullname":"Bala", "age":30, "car":{"model":{"nickname":"jessica"}}}

#Third Document

{ "fullname":"Bala", "age":25, "car":{"model":{"nickname":"hilica"}}}

#Fourth Document

{ "fullname":"Bala", "age":30 }
```

*1.The query should be such that return documents that has a field car.model.nickname exists and fullname is "Bala".
2.Answer should be second and third document.*

I tried the below one with both match or term but of no use

```
GET index-bala/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "must" : [
                { "exists": { "field": "car.model.nickname" } },
                { "term" : { "fullname": "bala"} }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to find solution without making the question complex.
Here is the real example.
Query Requirement was that field "content.system.cpu" exists and hostname value equals to "balahost1.com"

Its similar like metric beat Mapping :

```
{
   "index-bala": {
      "mappings": {
         "type-bala": {
            "properties": {
               "@timestamp": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
               },
               "content": {
                  "properties": {
                     "@timestamp": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                     },
                     "@version": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "beat": {
                        "properties": {
                           "hostname": {
                              "type": "string"
                           },
                           "name": {
                              "type": "string"
                           },
                           "version": {
                              "type": "string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "host": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "metricset": {
                        "properties": {
                           "module": {
                              "type": "string"
                           },
                           "name": {
                              "type": "string"
                           },
                           "rtt": {
                              "type": "long"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "system": {
                        "properties": {
                           "cpu": {
                              "properties": {
                                 "cores": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "idle": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "double"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "iowait": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "double"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "irq": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "nice": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "softirq": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "double"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "steal": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "system": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "double"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "user": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "double"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "filesystem": {
                              "properties": {
                                 "available": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "device_name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                 },
                                 "files": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "free": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "free_files": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "mount_point": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                 },
                                 "total": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "used": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "bytes": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       },
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "memory": {
                              "properties": {
                                 "actual": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "free": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       },
                                       "used": {
                                          "properties": {
                                             "bytes": {
                                                "type": "long"
                                             },
                                             "pct": {
                                                "type": "double"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "free": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "swap": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "free": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       },
                                       "total": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       },
                                       "used": {
                                          "properties": {
                                             "bytes": {
                                                "type": "long"
                                             },
                                             "pct": {
                                                "type": "double"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "total": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "used": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "bytes": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       },
                                       "pct": {
                                          "type": "double"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "process": {
                              "properties": {
                                 "cmdline": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                 },
                                 "cpu": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "start_time": {
                                          "type": "date",
                                          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                                       },
                                       "total": {
                                          "properties": {
                                             "pct": {
                                                "type": "long"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "fd": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "limit": {
                                          "properties": {
                                             "hard": {
                                                "type": "long"
                                             },
                                             "soft": {
                                                "type": "long"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       },
                                       "open": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "memory": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "rss": {
                                          "properties": {
                                             "bytes": {
                                                "type": "long"
                                             },
                                             "pct": {
                                                "type": "long"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       },
                                       "share": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       },
                                       "size": {
                                          "type": "long"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                 },
                                 "pgid": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "pid": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "ppid": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                 },
                                 "state": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                 },
                                 "username": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "tags": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "hostname": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "service": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Sample Data:

Data 1:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-25T10:13:35.536Z",
    "content": {
      "metricset": {
        "name": "memory",
        "rtt": 173,
        "module": "system"
      },
      "beat": {
        "version": "5.2.2",
        "name": "balahost1.com",
        "hostname": "balahost1.com"
      },
      "@timestamp": "2017-04-25T10:13:33.180Z",
      "type": "metricsets",
      "system": {
        "memory": {
          "used": {
            "bytes": 3219914752,
            "pct": 0.8117
          },
          "free": 747134976,
          "actual": {
            "free": 1879838720,
            "used": {
              "pct": 0.5261,
              "bytes": 2087211008
            }
          },
          "swap": {
            "used": {
              "bytes": 200433664,
              "pct": 0.0482
            },
            "free": 3960311808,
            "total": 4160745472
          },
          "total": 3967049728
        }
      },
      "@version": "1",
      "host": "balahost1.com",
      "tags": [
        "beats_input_raw_event"
      ]
    },
    "hostname": "balahost1.com",
    "service": "index-bala"
  }
```

Data 2

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-25T10:13:35.532Z",
    "content": {
      "@timestamp": "2017-04-25T10:13:33.179Z",
      "type": "metricsets",
      "system": {
        "cpu": {
          "nice": {
            "pct": 0.0001
          },
          "system": {
            "pct": 0.0121
          },
          "iowait": {
            "pct": 0.0012
          },
          "irq": {
            "pct": 0
          },
          "steal": {
            "pct": 0
          },
          "softirq": {
            "pct": 0.0002
          },
          "cores": 2,
          "user": {
            "pct": 0.0189
          },
          "idle": {
            "pct": 0.9675
          }
        }
      },
      "metricset": {
        "module": "system",
        "name": "cpu",
        "rtt": 201
      },
      "beat": {
        "name": "balahost1.com",
        "hostname": "balahost1.com",
        "version": "5.2.2"
      },
      "@version": "1",
      "host": "balahost1.com",
      "tags": [
        "beats_input_raw_event"
      ]
    },
    "hostname": "balahost1.com",
    "service": "index-bala"
  }
```

Data 3:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-25T10:13:35.536Z",
    "content": {
      "metricset": {
        "name": "memory",
        "rtt": 173,
        "module": "system"
      },
      "beat": {
        "version": "5.2.2",
        "name": "balahost2.com",
        "hostname": "balahost2.com"
      },
      "@timestamp": "2017-04-25T10:13:33.180Z",
      "type": "metricsets",
      "system": {
        "memory": {
          "used": {
            "bytes": 3219914752,
            "pct": 0.8117
          },
          "free": 747134976,
          "actual": {
            "free": 1879838720,
            "used": {
              "pct": 0.5261,
              "bytes": 2087211008
            }
          },
          "swap": {
            "used": {
              "bytes": 200433664,
              "pct": 0.0482
            },
            "free": 3960311808,
            "total": 4160745472
          },
          "total": 3967049728
        }
      },
      "@version": "1",
      "host": "balahost2.com",
      "tags": [
        "beats_input_raw_event"
      ]
    },
    "hostname": "balahost2.com",
    "service": "index-bala"
  }
```

Data 4

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-25T10:13:35.532Z",
    "content": {
      "@timestamp": "2017-04-25T10:13:33.179Z",
      "type": "metricsets",
      "system": {
        "cpu": {
          "nice": {
            "pct": 0.0001
          },
          "system": {
            "pct": 0.0121
          },
          "iowait": {
            "pct": 0.0012
          },
          "irq": {
            "pct": 0
          },
          "steal": {
            "pct": 0
          },
          "softirq": {
            "pct": 0.0002
          },
          "cores": 2,
          "user": {
            "pct": 0.0189
          },
          "idle": {
            "pct": 0.9675
          }
        }
      },
      "metricset": {
        "module": "system",
        "name": "cpu",
        "rtt": 201
      },
      "beat": {
        "name": "balahost2.com",
        "hostname": "balahost2.com",
        "version": "5.2.2"
      },
      "@version": "1",
      "host": "balahost2.com",
      "tags": [
        "beats_input_raw_event"
      ]
    },
    "hostname": "balahost2.com",
    "service": "index-bala"
  }
```

**The final answer which i found without modifying the mapping is like below.**

```
GET index-bala/_search
{
    "min_score": 1.0,
   "query": {

      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "hostname": "balahost1.com"
               }

            },
            {
               "exists": {
                  "field": "content.system.cpu"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: @sam Can you provide mappings for `name` and `car` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "must" : [
                { "term" : { "name" : "Bala" } },
                { "exists": { "field": "car" } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit** Mapping for `hostname` field is `{"type": "string"}`, which means that the field is analyzed and if you will search `{match: {"hostname":"xxxxhostname.com"}}`than result will also include the documents with field name `"anyhost.com"` (Have a look at elasticsearch [analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-analyzers.html) for more details). The reason is the elasticsearch's analyzers. Also you can't search with term query on analyzed field.

You need to store the not analyzed value of the `hostname` field to be able to execute `term` query over it. As I understand, you are using the 2.x version of the elasticsearch, so the [documentation link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/multi-fields.html) also for it. You need something like this for `hostname` field mappings

```
"hostname": {
  "type": "string",
  "fields": {
    "raw": { 
      "type":  "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

And you need to query not over the `hostname` but over the `hostname.raw` with `term` query.

Or if you don't `hostname` to be analyzed, you can just make it not analyzed and query over it

```
"hostname": {
  "type": "string",
  "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

Comment: If mapping of field `name` is `text` then you need to modify `term` query little by replacing `name` with `name.keyword`. If you don't have `name.keyword` mutlifield defined in mapping then replace `term` query with `match` query.

Comment: @avr right, you need to modify query for `name` field according to filed mappings

Comment: Hi Ruben @avr. please try answering. I have modified the document to be exact and the query doesn't seem to work. When i use "match", with name "ala", it still returns unexpected result(1st, 2nd and 3rd document) with maxscore less. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Sam the query you provided is working as expected with default mapping. Please update your question with mappings of `name` and `car` to help you further.

Comment: Can you get your document mappings from elasticsearch and post it here? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Comment: @avr Its default mapping and also the above query(with term) returns nothing where as match query returns 1st,2nd and 3rd document with less _score :(

Comment: I created the sample node with your data and elasticsearch default mappings, and result is what you want to see. here is the screenshot of the query https://ibb.co/g0bNt5

Comment: Can you show as the result of the following request `GET cg-prod-metric/_mapping` ?

Comment: @RubenVardanyan Yes. Now I have updated the real scenario which i am facing. The query with match returns both balahost1.com and balahost2.com.

Comment: @RubenVardanyan Thanks a lot for the explanation :) . I have also updated one solution in the post which i think will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142600/discussion-between-ruben-vardanyan-and-sam).